# Proving $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(f(x))^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} dx \gt 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was supposed to show that $$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(x)g(x)}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} dx$$ is an inner product. The question basically said to prove symmetry, bilinearity, and that $\langle f,f \rangle \gt 0$ where $f \ne 0$.

Now, I have already shown symmetry and bilinearity. However, I am stuck with the last part. I would have to prove that $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(f(x))^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} dx \gt 0$$ but I have no clue how to do that. Could someone explain where should I start? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the integrand is positive.  When it exists, the Riemann integral is positive definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking! If we assume the integral exists, then $f^2(x)\geq0$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}\geq0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. Since we assume that $f$ is not identically $0$, then this integral is of a positive function and the integral is positive.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The integral of a positive function is positive.

Comment: I am curious why there is a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $g(x) > 0$ almost everywhere and $E$ is a set of positive measure, that is, $m(E) > 0$.  Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $\int_E g(x) dx \leq 0$.  Let $E_n = \{x \in E: g(x) > 1/n \}$. Then $E = \cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ and since $g(x) > 0$ almost everywhere, there exists an $n$ such that $m(E_n)>0$.  Hence,

$\int_E g(x) dx \geq \int_{E_n} g(x) dx > \frac{1}{n} m(E_n) > 0 $ ,

a contradiction.